# Unable to host IIS Express site with visual studio code

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I've been trying out visual studio code and i am trying to host asp.net core web app on IIS Express but i can't get it to work (403.14). The same project launches fine when i run it with visual studio 2017 with IIS Express attached.

I am using IIS Express plugin for visual studio code. The code compiles and runs smoothly with dotnet run. Also i've compared both [default iis express config file](https://pastebin.com/BdEax60w)  and [visual studio 2017 config file](https://pastebin.com/3zterqq9)  and they seem to match. Can anyone help me out i can't seem to find a logical solution to this?

Comment: Please See this First. [How-do-I-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Visual Studio runs IIS Express to host ASP.NET Core apps via certain tricks, https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3 which you cannot easily replicate on Visual Studio Code.